# IE8/IE9 Bug - Unexpected behavior when using IE filters

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have created an html block with the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="float">info<br/>info<br/>info</div>
    <div class="fluid">
        <div class ="fluidinner">
            <div class="text">one two</div>
            <div class="cleardiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and a second block with the exact same code, except that *class="fluid"* is changed to *class="fluid2"* this time.

The CSS is:

```
.float {
    background-color:pink;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.fluid {
    background-color:#d3dadb;
    padding:5px;
}
.fluid2 {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3dadb', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
    padding:5px;
}
.fluidinner {
    background-color: gray;
}
.cleardiv {
    clear:both;
}
```

So *"fluid"* has a solid background while *"fluid2"* has a background gradient using IE filter property *"filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3dadb', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 )"*

The result (screen shot): http://s14.postimage.org/v8qn1wvin/iebug.jpg

"fluid2" although clear does not extend to its container's height.

Jsfiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/waGEk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the gradient to the container: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waGEk/2/)